# How to setup apache virtual host with IIS intalled

Tags: php, apache, iis, wamp

I have wamp and IIS installed on my Windows 7 PC. I already changed `Listen 88` and `ServerName localhost:88` in my http.conf file. I can browse both wamp server and iis server.

But The problem is I want to create a VirtualHost on Apache. This is my code

**http.conf** file

```
<VirtualHost *:88>
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/test_php"
  ServerName phptest.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

**host** file

```
127.0.0.1 phptest.dev
```

But when I go to phptest.dev, It is automatically shows the IIS server page.

Comment: That is because your browser is using port 80 to go to phptest.dev, if you try phptest.dev:88, you should be redirected to the apache virtual host.

Comment: Don't use WAMP. Download VMWare Player and Ubuntu (or any other distribution of your choice) and work on a LAMP stack.

Comment: @LukaszKujawa : why you say do not use WAMP. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: @soumya-biswas : this is an artificial environment for PHP web application. Vast majority of production environments is LAMP. Coding for Windows might produce some inconsistencies. It's also a DEV nightmare. What if you have to compile an extension? What if you have to compile a lib for that extension (you need some additional parameters). Finally, it's unwise to integrate DEV environment with desktop. Even if one uses linux as his desktop I would recommend to keep DEV away (vm server, remote server).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using URL `http://phptewst.dev:88`, and not `http://phptest.dev` (which is really ... `http://phptest.dev:80`).

Add into httpd.conf these lines -

```
Listen 88
NameVirtualHost *:88
```

The first line will make Apache bind to port 88 (on all IPs). The second line will set up name-based hosts on port 88.

And remove these lines -

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
```

As IIS will be listening on those ports.

Though that's really not the best way to handle this, instead, just bind Apache and IIS on different IPs (not ports). Have IIS take 127.0.0.1 and Apache 127.0.0.2, or the LAN IP, or the WAN IP.

```
Listen 127.0.0.2:80
```

You can also have Apache (port 80) act as a Proxy to IIS (port 8080), that way you can have everything go through one IP and port 80. Setup a front-end VirtualHost and add a ProxyPass line inside...

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

(*I use WampDeveloper Pro, not WampServer, but it's all about the same so the above instructions should work for you)

> this is an artificial environment for PHP web application.

That comment is not 100% correct. Apache, PHP, and MySQL all have millions of users on Windows. And developing cross-platform will in itself help you find all kinds of bugs (from my personal experience).